Single outcome, repeated covariates in time: linear mixed models?
I have a dataset where I want to predict an outcome (EDSS at last follow up, measured in a numeric scale which is from 0 to 10, including only .5 decimals). From each patient, I have exactly 2 measures of biomarkers from each patient. I would like to create a predictive model using the biomarkers to predict EDSS at last follow up.
I tried linear mixed models, but it throws an error because convergence is not achieved. This is the formula I am using
EDSS_lastfollow ~ nfl + (1|ID)
I have tried using a gaussian link function and also using the outcome as a ordinal variable, but I could not reach convergence. I suspect it is because I do not really have a repeated outcome, but repeated covariates. I would like to take into account the ID variability of the covariates to model it. Do you have any idea on how I could proceed to model it? Just a simple lm would be better?

If you only have one observation of your outcome per participant, you can't use a linear mixed model (multilevel regression) and yes, this is probably why your model doesn't converge. Linear mixed models are for data in which you have several outcome observations per participant.
It is possible to predict a single outcome (i.e., an outcome with only one data point per participant) with a "repeated-measures predictor" (i.e. a predictor with more than 1 data point per participant) within multilevel structural equation framework. This question and answers provide some tips.
An alternative is to average or sum the biomarker indicators for each participant and use a single-level model.
